# JOIN instead of NOT EXISTS query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables,

One table which updates the postings to a Platform (It has all the status)
The other one which has only current status posted to ERP system.

I need to report the list of ID which are posted in platformbut not in ERP.

TABLE 1 : PLATFORM_TABLE

```
    ID  DOC_STATUS
10001   POSTED
10001   AVAIL TO POST
10002   AVAIL TO POST
10003   POSTED
10003   AVAIL TO POST
```

TABLE 2 : ERP

```
ID  DOC_STATUS
10001   AVAIL TO POST
10002   AVAIL TO POST
10003   POSTED
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT : Only 10001 because that is the only id posted in Table 1 but not in Table 2.

```
ID
10001
```

I tried using the below query and it works fine but due to performance i need to use only joins . Can you please guide on how to convert this query to join.

```
SELECT a.ID
  FROM ERP_TABLE a 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT ID FROM PLATFORM_TABLE b
    WHERE a.ID = b.ID
      AND a.DOC_STATUS  = 'POSTED');
```

Comment: you show 10001  in both tables.

Comment: @OldProgrammer :  I did not get you clearly.

Comment: you wrote, "Only 10001 because that is the only id posted in Table 1 but not in Table 2."  10001 is in both tables.  so how does that meet your requirement?

Comment: Yes It is there in both the tables but if you see table 1 has status POSTED where as table 2 has no POSTED for ID 10001. So I need to bring such records from Table 2.

Answer (score 3):

I think you got the anti join wrong. Your English phrasing says it:

> Only 10001 because that is the only id posted in Table 1 but not in Table 2.

So that translates to "all in table 1 (platform_table) for which there does not exist anything in table 2 (erp_table)"

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM platform_table a
WHERE a.doc_status = 'POSTED'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM erp_table b
  WHERE b.id = a.id
  AND b.doc_status = 'POSTED'
);
```

If you have to do this anti join with an actual join (I don't think you have to, Oracle should produce the same anti join execution plan), then you could do it like this:

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM platform_table a
LEFT JOIN erp_table b
  ON b.id = a.id
  AND b.doc_status = 'POSTED'
WHERE a.doc_status = 'POSTED'
AND b.id IS NULL
```

A third option is to use `MINUS`

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM platform_table a
WHERE a.doc_status = 'POSTED'
MINUS
SELECT b.id
FROM erp_table b
WHERE b.doc_status = 'POSTED'
```

Since this is about performance, I'm positive that indexes on `(id, doc_status)` will be beneficial on both tables.

Comment: Query might not work..May be I did not mention it correctly. I need to bring the IDs from ERP(T2) table not in PLATFORM.

If I take 10001 from T1 and T2 .. It has STATUS ='POSTED' in T1 but not in T2. So I need to print T2.ID ... Where has no other id has such..

In Short.. "Bring IDs which are POSTED in platform but not in ERP

Comment: @PRAJ: *"Bring IDs which are POSTED in platform but not in ER"* - All 3 of my suggestions do exactly that.